# check the side cells in a matrix (Kotlin)

Tags: arrays, kotlin, multidimensional-array

I'm working on a minesweeper program and I need to check the adjacent cells in a matrix to count how many mines are around the selected cell by its index. I'm new to this language and unsure how to check adjacent cells. Can anyone provide assistance? I'm available to answer any questions or concerns.

the code:

```
fun countMines(mines: Int) {
    val left = 0
    val bottom = n
    val right = n
    val top = 0

    for (i in 0 until tablero.size) {
        for (j in 0 until i) {
            // Check adjacent cells here
        }
        println()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, when you're iterating an array or list, you should not iteration from 0 all the way up to the size, because that is one too big and will reach outside it (the size plus one more for the 0). Either you can use `0 until tablero.size`, or `0..tablero.size - 1` or more simply, you can use `indices` so you don't have to type out the range.

For the inner range that iterates the rows in the outer loop's columns, you need to iterate all the rows. It doesn't make sense for `i` to be part of the range you're looping. If you did that, you would only be looping through the bottom triangular half of your square (if it's a square matrix). So here's how to fix that first part:

```
for (i in tablero.indices) {
    for (j in tablero[i].indices) {
        val currentCell = tablero[i][j]
        // check the neighbors...
    }
}
```

Now we are iterating every cell coordinate in the matrix. For each cell, you want to look at all the neighbors. This is done by looking up cells that are +1 or -1 from `i` and `j`. For instance, if we are looking at cell `tablero[i][j]` and we want to look at the cell to the left of it, we check `tablero[i-1][j]`. When you do these checks, you must be careful not to check out of bounds. For instance, if `i` is zero, there is no cell to the left, and `tablero[i-1]` would give you an IndexOutOfBoundsException because there cannot be a `tablero[-1]`. Likewise, if `i` is equal to `tablero.size - 1`, then there is no cell to the right of it.